# How can you place query results into an arbitrarily large array?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, mysqli

I have a site with friends list, and such. I use while loops to iterate through the lists, and I wanted to use a foreach loop instead.

The while loop works just as it should there's no problem with it. I'm not asking how to use a foreach loop. But when I tried changing the while loop I realized the following code;

```
   <?php

$my_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$request = "SELECT `request_from` FROM `friend_requests` WHERE `request_to`='$my_id' ";
$request_query = mysqli_query($conn, $request);
while ($run_request = mysqli_fetch_array($request_query)){
$from = $run_request['request_from'];
$username = getuser($from, 'username');

echo"<table>";
echo "<tr><td>".$username."</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "<br />";
}


output: 

sammy davis jr
frank sinatra
dean martin
```

Doesn't produce **AN** array the contains friends, it contains an arbitrary number of arrays, that have only one element in them. As when I do

```
print_r($runrequest);

output:

Array ( [0] => 20 [request_from] => 20 ) 
Array ( [0] => 21 [request_from] => 21 ) 
Array ( [0] => 19 [request_from] => 19 )
```

So my question is, is there a way for me to rewrite my **mysqli_query** so that I produce only one, arbitrarily large, array that I would then iterate through with a foreach loop. As opposed to the query I have which produces an arbitrary number of arrays, that I have to iterate through with a while loop.

Comment: I just did print_r(...)  to show that a series of arrays were being produced and not one

Comment: Sorry, getuser(); is a special function I wrote to print a username based off of a uid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$run_request` is an array of just the 1 row/result per iteration. If you want an array with all the data build it in the loop. You don't need the `getuser` function, you can use a `join` to get the user's names with the one query.

```
$request = "SELECT u.name as name FROM `friend_requests` as fr 
            join users as u 
            on u.userid = fr.request_from 
            WHERE `request_to`='$my_id' ";
$request_query = mysqli_query($conn, $request);
while ($run_request = mysqli_fetch_array($request_query)){
     $users[] = $run_request['name'];
}
print_r($users);
```

Alternatively you could use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php.